# How can I execute a XSS with these conditions?

Tags: web-application, penetration-test, xss

I am trying to learn penetration testing and I have downloaded a vulnerable application called "Bodgeit Store". I have finished almost all the challenges except one which is to execute a Cross-Site Scripting attack. I looked through the source code of the app and found the following Java code:

```java
if (request.getMethod().equals("POST") && comments != null)
{
    anticsrf = request.getParameter("anticsrf");
        if (anticsrf != null && anticsrf.equals(request.getSession().getAttribute("anticsrf")))
            {
                // Strip script tags, because that will make everything alright...
                comments = comments.replace("<script>", "");
                comments = comments.replace("</script>", "");
                // And double quotes, just to make sure
                comments = comments.replace("\"", "");
            .................
            }
}
```

The challenge says:

> "Display a popup using: `<script>alert("XSS")</script>`"

but looking at the source, we find that the `<script>` and `</script>` tags are replaced by null characters. Also I cannot make a GET request because the code also verifies whether the request is a POST request or not.

I have tried and succeeded in executing an alert box using other methods like using an external .js file and so, but I really want to find how one could complete this challenge.
Please give me some suggestions on how to go about solving this one.

Comment: You could just add some whitespace and use `'` instead of `"`: <script >alert('XSS')</script > There are also [plenty other methods](http://ha.ckers.org/xss.html).

Comment: Another genius!! I love your answer too...I never thought about adding spaces and i got a pop too but for some weird reasons, the challenge is still showing up as not solved...But i don't care. I just like your answers..Yours and Ilmari Karonen's...Thank You guys...:)
PS: I had looked through the cheat sheet already but the challenge was to solve it using

Answer (score 12):

Besides [Gumbo's nice and simple answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10486372), another possibility would be to use the last `replace()` call to bypass the earlier ones, for example like this:

```
<scr"ipt>alert('XSS')</scr"ipt>
```

In fact, I suspect this might be the solution that the author of the challenge was expecting: there's not much point in stripping double quotes *except* to deliberately allow this particular attack, and the "just to make sure" comment even calls attention to it.

Of course, even if the code *didn't* strip double quotes, you could still do this:

```
<scr</script>ipt>alert('XSS')</scr</script>ipt>
```

Comment: That’s not JavaScript but Java.

Comment: Oh, that changes things.  Let me replace my answer with another solution, then.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen you are a genius. I never thought of this solution. That did not help solve the problem but I very much like your solution. Thank You :)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Fantastic. Your second solution worked perfectly for my purposes. Simple but very effective.

Answer (score 3):

Upon reviewing your question again, I finally see what the challenge is trying to get you to achieve. Notice how the anti-XSS code is enveloped by an `if` statement that checks for the presence of an `anticsrf` parameter and whether it is equal to the `anticsrf` object present in the user's session object. By breaking any of these two conditions, you can effectively make the code above (`<script>alert("XSS")</script>`) work. In other words, if you exclude the `anticsrf` parameter from the request or change the `anticsrf` parameter in the request to something arbitrary, the `comment` parameter will be reflected verbatim because the code block stripping the XSS code will be skipped.

## Other Stuff To Consider:

The `<script>` tag container is not the only place you can XSS. Take a look at the other HTML tags and what they can do. For instance, the following works with `<img>` tags:

```
<img src=javascript:alert('hi'); />
```

There are also the `onload`, `onmouseover`, etc. event handlers associated with a whole bunch of tags in HTML that could be leveraged for this purpose. My best suggestion would be to take a look at the [HTML specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/) to get some more ideas. If you're going to become a web pen tester then you'll certainly want to arm yourself with that knowledge.

Comment: Are there any browsers left that will respect a javascript: scheme URI for an image source? (Obviously you shouldn't let such code through as people do use old browsers, but it might not be useful for a demonstration of XSS).

Comment: @Quentin: I just tested this, and Firefox 12, at least, _will_ execute `javascript:` URIs in `img` `src` attributes, but won't permit them to call `alert()` (or, presumably, do anything else that would violate same-origin restrictions). I even found [an old bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=351370) about a hole in this mechanism, which may provide some insight into how and why it works like that.

Comment: @Quentin: there are plenty of other ways to get around that like `<img src=somethingWrong onerror=alert('hi')>`. HTML is really flexible and the possibilities for getting around naive anti-XSS implementations are endless.

Answer (score 1):

**Auto-submitting form:**

```
<html>
    <body onload="document.forms[0].submit()">
        <form method="POST" action="...">
        ...
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**XSS without script tag:**

```
<img src="missing" onerror="..." />
```

Answer (score 1):

I like some of the other inventive postings here for answers.

Here's some simple & stupids that popped into my head right away:

```
<script >alert('XSS')</script >
<SCRIPT>alert('XSS')</SCRIPT>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could insert other types of space & tabulators among the tags to bypass the filter.

For example:

```
<scr&#x9ipt>alert('XSS')</scr&#x9ipt>
```

The code above will put a tab between r & i in both tags, thus making the code ineffective.

To surpass the PHP script, you could try using grave accents (`) which are used in HTML but not filtered by most handwritten filters.